# how to create an application of AudioRecorder test in which audio is recorded by the system as well as from the environment

Tags: android

How to create an application of AudioRecorder test in which audio is recorded by the system as well as from the environment I mean system automatically record his voice as well as the user voice please help me to write code?

I tried but I don't get any clue how to write code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.